# Why is my android library making an extra apk when used in another project?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-library, gradle-plugin

I have created a simple android library. The problem is, whenever it is used in any project, and an apk is generated for the project, two different instances of the apk are installed.

[image]

Like in the example above, Once I add the library in the project and run it, two diffrent apks are installed.

I know the problem is with the library. [You can access the libray here](https://github.com/MartinMbae/Sample/).

Below is the gradle file of my library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'KenyanCounties' // Repo name in bintray dashboard
    bintrayName = 'studios.luxurious.kenya47counties' // package name of the bintray repo

    publishedGroupId = 'com.martinmbae.kenyan.47counties'   // this is the ID we want to see in implementation line
    libraryName = 'kenyacountieslibrary'     // this is the module name of library
    artifact = 'library'        // this is the artifact we want to see in implementation line

    libraryDescription = 'An android library that displays all kenyan libraries for selection. Each library countains a name, county number and a flag' // description of library

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/MartinMbae/Sample'    // git repo url
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/MartinMbae/Sample.git' // git repo vcs url

    libraryVersion = '1.0.1'      // library version

    developerId = 'martinmbae'                // This is your bintray username
    developerName = 'Martin Mbae'              // Developer's name
    developerEmail = 'martinmbae.codemaster@gmail.com'                // Developer's email

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'  // for example, The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'   // for example, http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]    // array of licenses, for example, ["Apache-2.0"]
}



    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
apply from: 'publish.gradle'
//apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

Comment: Have you changed your package name ?@Martin Mbae

Comment: Yes I have @Sarthak. The answer from NileshRathod worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check your manifest file

I think you have added `<intent-filter>` in more than one activity

Make sure `<intent-filter>` added in just your main or default activity like this

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asknilesh.demo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your library is declaring a launcher `Activity` in its manifest, in addition to the one in your main app:

```xml
        <activity android:name=".activities.Kenya47Counties">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If you remove that from the library's `AndroidManifest.xml`, your problem should go away.